# "Rule all" input with wildcards

Tags: python, snakemake

I've got an input file per user (their name has the form db-user.participant). I want to take those files as input and then a test script has to output a file per participant per sensor (there is a second list with sensors). My code is working but I was wondering if this is the "snakemake" way to accomplish what I want.

```py
SENSORS=["s1", "s2"]
DBS_USERS={"db1":["p1", "p2"]}

def db_user_path(paths):
    new_paths = []
    for db, users in DBS_USERS.items():
        for user in users:
            for path in paths:
                new_paths.append(path.replace("db", db).replace("user", user))
    return new_paths

print(db_user_path(expand("data/raw/db/user/{sensor}.csv", sensor=SENSORS)))

rule all:
    input:
        db_user_path(expand("data/raw/db/user/{sensor}.csv", sensor=SENSORS))

rule create_dataset:
    input:
        "data/external/{db}-{user}.participant"
    output:
        expand("data/raw/{{db}}/{{user}}/{sensor}.csv", sensor=SENSORS)
    script:
        "src/data/test.R"
```

For example if I have:

```
db1-p1.participant
db1-p2.participant
sensors = ["s1","s2"]
```

The output should be:

```
db1/p1/s1.csv
db1/p1/s2.csv
db1/p2/s1.csv
db1/p2/s2.csv
```